# How to center navigation bar tags?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have been trying to center these navigation tags but I cant spot my mistake from the code.. Also they are not coming out as a links. Even they dont have a real address yet I cant "click" on them. It might be very simple thing but I just cant find it. I have tried to change floating from left to center but it doesnt do any difference. The code still misses hovers etc. but those I can add by myself. Thank you before hand if someone can help this hopeless beginner coder.

Here is my html:

```
<body>

<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="bgimage" src="tausta3.jpg" />
                <div id="content">
                    <p align="center">Art Portfolio by (name)</p>

                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <p align="center"><li><a href="#">Art</a></li></p>
                    <p align="center"><li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <p align="center"><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div> 
</body>`
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: palatino linotype;
color: white;
font-size: 50px;
}

#bgimage {
position:fixed; 
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index:1;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#content {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top: 0;
z-index:70;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#nav{

position: absolute;
left:100px;
top:0;
z-index: 90;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
color: white;

}

#ul li {
list-style-type: none;
float:left; 
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid `li`should be children of a `ul`

Comment: Also, using tables for layout or positioning everything is a poor method. There are much better methods. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: What @Paulie_D said. Also: http://jsfiddle.net/xez8a0ma/